# Which to choose and when: Web content, Dynamic List Records or Specific Model?

Tags: liferay

I find that Liferay concepts are quite confusing.

When I add new items, I don't know what is the best to choose:

- Use the web content concept with template and structure
- Use the dynamic list records
- Use a specific model (using service builder).

All of these are really similars and can achieve same goals.

Have you got any clue or advice on what concept to choose when you develop some new features in Liferay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the components in this way :

- Web Content : Web contents provide convenient way to create, update, view, modify, create RSS feeds, customize the content of the web site. It is one of the main component of the Liferay CMS. You should use web content when,

  - You have static content and want to show to the site.
  - You have specific structure of the content (like content with an inline image and a document link), then please use web content with the structure and template
  - You want to use ready to use content portlets ( web content list, web content display, web content search) instead of creating new set of portlets for your own type.

After all this, Liferay provides customization of web contents by allowing user to add new content type, creating rss feeds, structures, templates, ready workflow, content type roles etc.

- Dynamic List : Consider dynamic list as a database with display functionality. Here, you can create a custom type of data and provide display functionality. If you have any requirement like user can create his/her own type of list maintain them, then go for it.
- Custom Portlet : If your requirement is very case/scenario specific that you cannot achieve using list or web content or any other Liferay portlets (blogs, wiki, knowledge based articles etc) then go for custom portlet, here please remember, that at every liferay upgrade, you need to review the portlet and update the code accordingly in case of any API change or something. For OOB portlets, Liferay takes care of it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It deends on what you want to have and how much control you want to have over your code.

- To make simplistic application use web content concept with template
  and structure.(need not to know technologies)
- -To make some complex applications use dynamic list records
- To make extremely complex applications and have full control over the flow use liferay service builder.(need t be a expert java programmer)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm a java programmer, so I've developed each of them several times but I don't see any web content limitation that a dynamic list record can solve, this is why I'm asking that ;)